# usage of exception in c++

Tags: c++, exception, std

In my project codding i have to use a try catch method to find the function execution status.

```
   try
   {
      //sample code
      //calling functions
      function1();
      function2();
      //........
   }
   catch(//need to catch exception)
   { 
    return failure;
   }
```

My requirement is that i have to catch all the exceptions that thrown from the try block

i have two options here,

1. catch(...)
2. catch(std::exception)

I think the first one will catch all the exceptions. And the second one, std::exception is the base class for all other exception classes in my program

```
   class MyException : public std::exception
   {
    // All the exceptions that i have use is derived from this class
   }.
```

Which is better and more efficient.

Is the both method works same way. Help me and suggest any method

Comment: Are you sure that your code is not calling any outside code that can throw exceptions not derived from std::exception?

Comment: its good practice to catch specific errors first followed by the catch all (...)

Comment: ok.  i agree with you.But whatever the exception is, i have to do only one thing. so i coded like this

Comment: @ rhalbersma: Yes . all the exceptions thrown from my code comes under that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always keep your specification as focused as possible so that you catch those that you *know* could be thrown, and catch derived exceptions (more specialised) before base ones:

```
try
{
    // Some stuff
}
catch (Derived& e)
{
    // Deal with specifics of Derived
}
catch (Base& e) 
{
    // Deal with general case of Base
}
```

*Never* use `catch(...)` except at the very top of your program stack (and certainly not in libraries.) When you do this, you cannot be sure about what caused the exception and therefore you cannot necessarily rely on things that you normaly would (such as memory management etc.)

Comment: This makes sense. I have to do only one thing if any exception thrown from the try block.

Ie, set the command status as failure. And no need to identify the cause for the exception. As you said like i can use catch(...)

Comment: I said *don't* use `catch(...) ` - if you know what exception is going to be thrown then catch that. If you don't - find out. Unless you are going to let your app terminate immediately, you should never try to catch every exception: What if you ran out of memory? Setting the command status would make no difference as your app would be zapped.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you'd work your way through the types which may be thrown in the following order:

```
catch (MyException& e) {
  ...
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
  ...
}
catch (...) {
  ...
}
```

This way, you can handle the specific errors/types first, and then fall back on the weak (or untyped) handlers when the preceding handlers do not match.

> Which is better and more efficient.

The order I recommended is best for handling by type. IMO, efficiency is not a concern in this scenario because correctness takes precedence and *hopefully* exceptions are thrown only under exceptional circumstances.

Comment: i agree with you. I had already said that i have to do only one thing in the catch block(the type of exception is not important).

So if change my code as you suggest... it will be code repetition.

Comment: I'm with @Justin on this one, efficiency shouldn't really be a  concern in the case of exception handling, correctness is the priority

Comment: i meant by the term 'efficient' is that, the catch block which can catch all the exception thrown from the program without missing any exceptions).

Comment: @AneeshNarayanan that you don't care to handle the thrown exception (apart from preventing it from leaving the calling function) wasn't clear in the OP. it's better to actually try to use the information provided by the exception than to ignore it, even if it seems repetitious. if you don't care to do more than swallow the error (**GASP!**) and `return failure`, then `catch(...)` would be the only option *unless* the implementations you call through here guarantee they throw `std::exception` types. if they throw an `int`, then `catch (std::exception& e)` would fail to catch that. (cont)

Comment: (cont) …but I can't think of any good reason why swallowing an untyped error would be favorable. even if you're going to `abort` right then and there, a typed exception would typically be useful if the section were entered.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to catch the specified exceptions only and use the catch(...) only in the main function. In my opinion the better way to use the exceptions is to implement one exception per module so each class will throw the specific exception related with the module of the class also different exceptions may be handled with a different way so I believe that

```
catch(const ExceptionType1& e){
}catch(const ExceptionType2& e){
}
```

is the better solution, also some other developer just reading this code will see which kind of exceptions could be thrown and handled....